# Uncaught TypeError - Symfony

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce, symfony-1.4

I need a hand to correct an Uncaught TypeError. 
The point is that I would like to use the tinyMCE editor, but it does not work.

[image: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property push of undefined]

I thought I would solve it:
-   replacing the older reference by a new tinymce installation src="/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"
-   or replacing the reference by a CDN: cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js

but the point is that I do not know how to do it.

I think this is done using the Symfony PHP framework.
I thought that the layout.php used was the following:

[image: source-code]

But I have changed the "XHTML 1.0 Transitional" header by "XHTML 9.0 Transitional" but I cannot see these changes if I reload the page.

I am bit, not to say, lot confused.

Any help will be really appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,

Pau Pujol

Answer (score 0):

Well I've finally solved it myself after a lot of hours and tries!!
I just let you know what I did in case somebody goes through the same problem.

I replaced the tiny_mce folder for an older version 3.5.11 (new versions come up with tinymce.min.js and no advance folder inside themes, I copied some plugins and I corrected some error functions...and voilà! worked!

Now that I am writting it seems quite easy, but actually it was quite tough (at least for me).

Well, greetings to everybody.

Pau Pujol